# How to set size on image source url?

Tags: php, html, url

I just want to ask how can i put size on my img url source?

Because I use this code but it's not working

```
 echo '<div class="image-company"><img src="('.$agent_image_url.', '600x400')" alt="" class="img-thumbnail"/></div>';
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images has `width` and `heihgt` attribute. Values in HTML attributes width/height are without 'px' units.

```
echo '<div class="image-company"><img src="'.$agent_image_url.'" alt="" width="600" height="400" class="img-thumbnail"/></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this way to give `height and width to img` Using `image attribute`

```
echo '<div class="image-company"><img src="'.$agent_image_url.'" width=600 height=400 alt="" class="img-thumbnail"/></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `width` and `height` as `style` attributes:

```
echo '<div class="image-company"><img src="'.$agent_image_url.'" alt="" class="img-thumbnail" style="width:600px; height:400px;" /></div>';
```